# Router with React Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm developing a Chrome extension with React but I can't get rid of this warning: `No routes matched location "/popup.html"`, it cause the app simply to not start.

I used [this template](https://github.com/VasilyShelkov/create-react-extension#creating-a-browser-extension) to create the app and my App.js looks like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute> <Dashboard /> </PrivateRoute> } />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route exact path="/update-profile" element={<PrivateRoute> <UpdateProfile /> </PrivateRoute> } />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Before using routes, having just `return (<Signup/>)` worked but not everything is broken.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found a simple answer if that can help people:

Just replace `import { BrowserRouter }` with `import { HashRouter }` and that will work perfectly fine